# jQuery doesn't recognize :not(.className) filtering

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

When I dynamically add a class to an element, pseudo filtering doesn't recognize that class.
This problem occurs when I use on() function, but everything is fine when I use live()

http://jsfiddle.net/AHyyq/1/

At the beginning, all list items are clickable. 
But after you press the button, "Ipsum" should not be clickable any more, and should not appear another "Not active" message.

```
$('.item:not(.active)').on('click', function(){
   $('<p>Not active</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.item:not(.active)', function(){
    $('<p>Not active</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(document).on`

```
$(document).on('click','.item:not(.active)', function(){
   $('<p>Not active</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```

[**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/AHyyq/6/)

Answer (score 0):

It is correct behavior. You are adding events to non active elements (all 3 .item's).
So it will not unbind events if you add class.

I would do something like this:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('.item:nth-child(2)').addClass('active').css('color','#F00');
});

$('.item').on('click', function() {    
    if($(this).is('.active')) return;

    $('<p>Not active</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AHyyq/9/

Answer (score -1):

[See here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
 $(document).on('click','.item:not(.active)', function(){
   $('<p>Not active</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```